# RN Release build fails, but debug runs. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have a react-native app that runs perfectly well in debug, but fails on a release build.
Running node 16.3.2 inside Windows 11 with react-native 0.63.4

Any thoughts on what to try would be greatly appreciated.

The build error from `gradlew assembleRelease` is:

```
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Projects\right-on-course-expo - ejectRelease-20220207\android\app\src\main\java\com\hordernit\rightoncourseapp\MainApplication.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.hordernit.rightoncourseapp;
^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The MainApplication.java referred to in the error is as follows:

```
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesDevLauncherController;
import expo.modules.devlauncher.DevLauncherController;
package com.hordernit.rightoncourseapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.hordernit.rightoncourseapp.generated.BasePackageList;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
    new BasePackageList().getPackageList()
  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return DevLauncherController.getInstance().getUseDeveloperSupport();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    @Override
    protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getJSBundleFile() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getJSBundleFile();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getLaunchAssetFile();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getBundleAssetName();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getBundleAssetName();
      }
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      UpdatesController.initialize(this);
    }

    DevLauncherController.initialize(this, getReactNativeHost());
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      DevLauncherController.getInstance().setUpdatesInterface(UpdatesDevLauncherController.initialize(this));
    }
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.hordernit.rightoncourseapp.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My /android/build.gradle file is as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

and the android/app/build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: (findProperty('expo.jsEngine') ?: "jsc") == "hermes",
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-constants/scripts/get-app-config-android.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.hordernit.rightoncourseapp'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('roc-app.jks')
            storePassword 'snip'
            keyAlias 'snip'
            keyPassword 'snip'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "./eas-build.gradle"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try declaring the package separately above the imports like this:

```
package com.hordernit.rightoncourseapp;

import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesDevLauncherController;
import expo.modules.devlauncher.DevLauncherController;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
//....
```

Comment: This file, I believe, was generated by the expo-cli when the app was first built for Android. Thanks very much, trying your suggestion...

Comment: Thanks very much, Sujal Kumar, this got me over the line. This will be documented for future reference. Love your work!